# Android Hybrid Remote App - On clicking Push notification open a specific app Page instead of Landing Page

Tags: cordova, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I have implemented a hybrid remote app for our Salesforce Community and also activated Push notifications for same.

By default, whenever you gets a push notification, tapping on it opens the app with the default Landing/Start Page as mentioned in the bootConfig.

I am trying to achieve if we can open any specific page other than landing page on Push notification click ?
We will have the specific details to be included inside Push payload.

Does anyone have any experience on this.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get a solution on this so in case anyone running into Similar situation,

We need to utilise the "OnDeviceReady" event to achieve this,

Steps involved in the Solution 
Since we are building a remote hybrid app for Salesforce Community, this code will go inside your  Community Landing Page,

Add the eventlistener in "Onload" js,
document.addEventListener("deviceready", myDeviceReadyListener, false);

Add the Push registration Logic in the "myDeviceReadyListener" method,

function myDeviceReadyListener() {
var push = PushNotification.init({
          "android": { "senderID": "<<<>>>>>" },
          "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"},
          "windows": {}
 });
push.on('notification', function(data) {
//This is optional as I am trying to show Push message as an Alert when the //app is in Foreground
    if(data.additionalData.foreground)
          window.alert(data.title+'\n'+data.message);
          //window.alert('insidePushDeviceReady'); 
          if(data.additionalData.coldstart){
               //redirecturl will be additional key in your payload to hold     //the relative url for redirection
                 window.open(data.additionalData.redirecturl);
        }
});
}

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Inside Android SenderID value - Please pass your gcm Project ID(Same as entered in BootConfig file)